# How to name an array before adding it to a group of arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way I can name an array before adding it to a group of arrays? I have the code below that gets a list of files from a dir, then gets the contents of the files listed and adds them to an array.

```
public function buildArray(){

$handsetFilenames = array();
$handsetArray     = array();

    if ($handle = opendir('path to file/')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            $handsetFilenames[] = $entry;
        }
    }

        foreach ($handsetFilenames as $match => $key){
            $file = file('handsets/'.$key);
            $handsetArray[] = $file;    
        }
    return $handsetArray;
}
```

When I output the `$hansetArray` I get a list just saying Array 23 times. When I output the arrays within the array they work fine, but i'd like them to be named after the file they're taken from i.e. the list from `$handsetFilenames`.

Edit: Apparently I'm not showing I've tried to solve this myself!!

I have tried to add this `$handsetArray[$key] = $file;` to make it an associate array, but this does still not work.

My output method is this:

```
$file_location = $fileLocation->buildArray();

foreach ($file_location as $match => $key){
    $page->addToBody($match.' = '.$key."</br>");    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

```
    foreach ($handsetFilenames as $match => $key){
        $file = file('handsets/'.$key);
        $handsetArray[$key] = $file; // added $key. Or add $match
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it turns out I wasn't outputting the key of the array, just the value :-)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Glad it helped.